# Toggle navbar on each navbar item click except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to toggle navbar when navigating with mobile when the user clicks each one of the navbar items except one which is a dropdown.

I am using this code:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-toggle').click();
});
```

The problem is that this code toggles the navbar with each item of the navbar on click. However, when I click the dropdown in the navbar, the navbar toggles and the user cannot see items in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it worked:

```
$('.nav :not(.dropdown) a') .on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar-toggle').click();
    });
```